# Datedif issue - convert number of days to "--Years--Months--Days" format

Tags: excel, function, formula

I should convert number of days to "--Years--Months--Days" format. I am mostly calculating the percentages of working days.

```
=DATEDIF(B2,C2,"y")&" years "&DATEDIF(B2,C2,"ym")&" months "&DATEDIF(B2,C2,"md")&" days"
```

works well for date to date. Here, I need numbers of days. in to "--Years--Months--Days" format.

e.g: 10 Sep 2021 to 01 Mar 2023 (546 days) 75% of 546 is 409.5 I need to calculate how many years months days of 409.5 days. Is it possible?

Comment: Since both years and months have a variable number of days, you will need to first define what you mean by a "year" and by a "month".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=DATEDIF(0,DATEDIF(B2,C2,"D")*0.75,"Y") & " Years, " & DATEDIF(0,DATEDIF(B2,C2,"D")*0.75,"YM") & " Months, " & DATEDIF(0,DATEDIF(B2,C2,"D")*0.75,"MD") & " Days"
```

Comment: Not possible to calculate from total days?

Comment: Replace `DATEDIF(B2,C2,"D")*0.75` with the total days

Comment: I have tried  DATEDIF(B2,C2,"D")*0.75 but this formula for 01-Ju2021 and 01-Ju2023 02 Years 0 Months 29 days; however without giving "0.75" getting 2Years 1 Months 0 Days. (Here I have given instead of 0.75, given 1)

Comment: My result is "1 Years, 5 Months, 30 Days
"

Comment: The same if it split in different cells =DATEDIF(0,DATEDIF(B4,C4,"D")*0.75,"Y") answer 1 year & =DATEDIF(0,DATEDIF(B4,C4,"D")*0.75,"YM") answer 5 months and =DATEDIF(0,DATEDIF(B4,C4,"D")*.075,"MD") answer 30 days - it should show as 1, 6, 0 in different cells.

Comment: Probably not going to get an exact answer as @ron-rosenfeld explains in the comments

Comment: not getting proper answer

Comment: Ya, using datedif probably is not the best solution for this.

Comment: Could you please let me know if there is any other solution?